# How create subscription based access for company or individual in Moodle or Drupal Opigno

Tags: php, drupal, moodle

I am very newbie to Moodleor Drupal Opigno and i want to do a subscription based access to course created by me.

I want to create few subscription for individual/company like Bronze, Silver, Gold and Platinum and custom like other company or website provide these days.

- **The Bronze subscription** available for individual and can access any course for the period of month or more depending the time period for which he/she pay.
- **The Silver subscription** available for company and can access any course for the period of month or more depending the time period for which company pay. Here company can add their own employees for the training and enroll the employees, but can not unroll the employees. Company can view all the badges, reports etc related to their employees and other company can not view or access other company record, but admin or manager can. A company can add maximum of 25 employees. If they want to add more employees then the company should upgrade their subscription plan.
- **The Gold subscription** available for company and can access any course for the period of month or more depending the time period for which company pay. Here company can add their own employees for the training and enroll the employees, but can not unroll the employees. Company can view all the badges, reports etc related to their employees and other company can not view or access other company record, but admin or manager can. A company can add maximum of 50 employees. If they want to add more employees then the company should upgrade their subscription plan.
- **The Platinum subscription** available for company and can access any course for the period of month or more depending the time period for which company pay. Here company can add their own employees for the training and enroll the employees, but can not unroll the employees. Company can view all the badges, reports etc related to their employees and other company can not view or access other company record, but admin or manager can. A company can add maximum of 100 employees. If they want to add more employees then the company should upgrade their subscription plan.
- The Custom subscription available for company and can access any course for the period of month or more depending the time period for which company pay. Here company can add their own employees for the training and enroll the employees, but can not unroll the employees. Company can view all the badges, reports etc related to their employees and other company can not view or access other company record, but admin or manager can. A company can add maximum of Nth employees depending upon their custom subscription.

Each Subscription plan will be associate to a manager except bronze which is for individual. Manager will track and assist the company and a single manager can be associate to multiple company.

Please someone assist to develop this kind of service or architecture in moodle or Drupal Opigno.

Answer (score 1):

The subscription as you describe doesn't come as standard in Moodle.

You will basically need to create an enrol plugin with the options mentioned.

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Enrolment_plugins

Maybe also take a look at cohorts in Moodle (audiences in Totara). This groups users together as a "cohort". So you could put employees into a cohort for a company for example.

https://docs.moodle.org/30/en/Cohorts

There is also an enrolment plugin for this in yoursite.com/enrol/cohort - maybe use this as a reference for your enrolment plugin.

https://docs.moodle.org/28/en/Cohort_sync

Also maybe have a look at Totara. It's a distribution of Moodle, extended for enterprises rather than education. The code is open source but based on a subscription model, so is not free initially.

https://www.totaralms.com/

Totara has dynamic audiences, so you could use indicators for staff to automatically add employees to an audience.

https://help.totaralearning.com/display/TL29/Audiences#Audiences-Dynamicaudiences

It also has organisation hierarchies which might be helpful.

https://help.totaralearning.com/display/TL29/Organisations

Answer (score 1):

Russells answer is quite complete already. Although, there are also other options to consider.

When you set it up, like Russell mentioned, with the cohort sync enabled, you still need to be able to add members to cohorts. Which can be done via, for example, the Coupon plugin (https://moodle.org/plugins/block_coupon). That way, you generated codes / PDF's you sell to the users, and let them create their own accounts and 'enroll' themselves to the cohort.

If you want an even completer solution, you could consider asking about the status of the webservices extensions to Coupon, to be able to interface it with your webshop itself.

I do agree with Russell though, that if you've got a larger budget, it might be wise to see if Totara is more interesting for you.
If you want to stick with Moodle, it might also be interesting for you to take a look at all the existing enrolment plugins at https://moodle.org/plugins/browse.php?list=category&id=22 and contact one of the authors of the plugins that work with payments, to see if your wishes can be integrated.